# Java Multithreading return value

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code that loop a process, the code is like this:

```
for (int z = 0; z < m_ID.length; z++) {
    expretdata = expret.Get_Expected_Return(sStartDate, sEndDate, m_ID[z], sBookName, nHistReturn,nMarketReturn, nCustomReturn);
    m_Alpha[z] = expretdata;
}
```

`Get_Expected_Return()` is an expensive method that take too long. So if `M_ID.length` more than 200, it will take a hour to complete the task.

I want to optimize it with multithread. I tried to save the return value to Map static global variable, and reorder it with key. Because I need data to be ordered by index of `M_ID.length`.

But, when I try to run the multithread some of threads return value = NULL, it looks like the thread doesn't run the method.

Is multithread the right way to do it? or give me any advice to optimize it.

Comment: straight-forward would be to spawn Threads, then use `join` and collect result in a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: The problem here is that communication between multiple threads is complicated, and need to be properly *synchronized* because otherwise different threads might see different data / no data / wrongly initialized objects etc. Concurrency and parallelism is a subject you need to study (https://amzn.to/2riOAPj) and its scope is waaay over a SO answer. You can try using a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`, but likely you'll soon get other problems elsewhere, too.

Comment: There is no `return` here. Post the code that does the `return` and we might have something worth answering. WIthout, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multithreaded can be very useful if your expensive methods are independent and don't use too much of a shared singular resource such as a single hard drive.

Your use case of ordered results can be solved using Callables and Futures:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


class Test
{       
    static final int CALLS = 10;

    static int slowMethod(int n) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return n+1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List<Future<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < CALLS ; i++)
        {
            final int finali = i;
            futures.add(executor.submit(()->slowMethod(finali)));               
        }
        for(Future<Integer> f: futures) {System.out.print(f.get());}
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 or above version, you can use parallelStream.

```
    m_Alpha = m_ID.parallelStream()
                 .map( z => {
                        return expret.Get_Expected_Return(sStartDate, sEndDate, m_ID[z], 
                                           sBookName, nHistReturn,nMarketReturn, nCustomReturn);
                  })
                 .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

*Type of constructor that is provided toArray method should be the same with the type of m_Alpha.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CompletableFuture` to execute this task in parallel. Here is an example.

```
// lets define a wrapper class which is responsible to put calculated data into the array-> 

private void longExecution(int index, DataType m_Alpah,  ... sStartDate, sEndDate, m_ID_index_z, sBookName, nHistReturn,nMarketReturn, nCustomReturn){
        m_Alpha[index] =  expret.Get_Expected_Return(sStartDate, sEndDate, m_ID_index_z, sBookName, nHistReturn,nMarketReturn, nCustomReturn);
}

// Now from your code:

...
CompletableFuture[] futures = new CompletableFuture[m_ID.length];
for (int z = 0; z < m_ID.length; z++) {
   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                    longExecution(z, m_Alpah, sStartDate, sEndDate, m_ID[z], sBookName, nHistReturn,nMarketReturn, nCustomReturn));
);
}
// waiting for completing all of the futures.
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();


// After this line:
//m_Alpha <- array will hold the result.
```